# Swift / UIWebView with xpath / css

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have an element of a website that I want to display within a UIWebView. The element has a unique ID for css as well as for xpath. Is it possible? How would I be able to do that? Help is very appreciated.

[image]

I usualy use this code:

```
let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://blablablabla.com")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

But I don't want to display the whole page. Only the element with that ID.

Comment: how is that comment supposed to help me in any way? I just want to display that element with that ID, not the whole page, as I'm used too in a webview

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes you are right. I've re-edited my question while you've written your comment. So. It is simly not possible?

Comment: I want to display the chat from a youtube livestream within that webview. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hpl9LJUPJuA

Comment: I'm sorry that I did confused you. I didn't mean to and I appreciate your effort in explaining me

Comment: I don't think this is possible if you are not willing to parse the html and remove all other content outside that `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `UIWebView`, not the newer `WKWebView`. What you need is an HTML parser (I chose [`HTMLReader`](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader)). After downloading the page content, extract the `div` you want and replace the page's `body` with the `innerHTML` of that `div`.

The code below gets the *Did you know* section on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page):

```
import HTMLReader

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadHTML()
}

func loadHTML() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("data is nil")
            return
        }

        let html = HTMLDocument(data: data, contentTypeHeader: nil)
        if let head = html.firstNodeMatchingSelector("head"),
            didYouKnow = html.firstNodeMatchingSelector("#mp-dyk") {
                let newHTML = "<html><head>\(head.innerHTML)</head><body>\(didYouKnow.innerHTML)</body></html>"
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(newHTML, baseURL: url)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is rather basic and is not 100% fool-proof though. See if it solves your problem.

Comment: and how do I put this into a UIWebView? like with what code do I call it? this code is for a UIButton? but I don't have any. sorry if this question is kinda dumb

Comment: I did have a button to trigger to function but you don't have to. You can call it from `viewDidLoad`. See my edited answer

Comment: I'm thankful for your edit and explanations, but I still have to ask... I'm used to do this with webview: `webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))`how am I putting the output of the loadHTML function into the webview?

Comment: sorry you have to dumb this down for me

Comment: You can tell the `webView` to load an URL, or you can ask it to load a HTML string. Check out the `self.webView.loadHTML(...)` line in my answer